# WallpaperManager.getDesiredMinimum...() functions return large values

Tags: android

So, a tiny bit of code:

```
final WallpaperManager mgr = (WallpaperManager)m_context.getSystemService(Service.WALLPAPER_SERVICE);
final int cx = mgr.getDesiredMinimumWidth();
final int cy = mgr.getDesiredMinimumHeight();
```

I'm running this in an device with a screen size of 800x600. cx ends up with a value of 1200, cy with 800... not too far from the right proportions, but much larger than screen size. Worse yet, the system seems to MEAN these values-- if I set the wallpaper to a smaller image, it gets scaled up to 1200x800, and then slapped onto the 800x600 screen-- distorted, blurry, and cropped, all at once.

Trying to create a bigger bitmap, with a solid-color border and the original image in the center, works... sort of. If I center my original image on the larger bordered image, it ends up way down at the lower right. of the actual screen. Better, but still less than ideal.

I *could* take my smaller, original bitmap, and put it in the center of a screen-sized area of the larger, making-wallpaper-manager-happy image. This would result in my image getting centered on the screen, woo woo, hurrah.

So, here I get to the question part: What horrible thing will go wrong if I do that? What thing will end-users do that reveals the immense swath of border below and right of the image I am trying to display?